¿Cómo puedo hacer que mis columnas en Android Studio sean del mismo ancho?
Estoy creando una tabla en mi  activity_main.xml y pienso meter diversos una lista larga de filas con "items", en los cuales meter imágenes y textos. He seguido las respuestas en otros posts de esta y otras páginas pero mi tabla no se ve de manera uniforme. Quiero que haya 2 columnas en tablas, que dichas columnas estén centradas y que los "items" que haya en las tablas estén centradas también, pero no he logrado esto. He ingresado dos imágenes y no están totalmente centradas además de que, por alguna razón, en el visualizador de la derecha de AndroidStudio, una imagen ocupa más espacio que otra. Esto no tendría sentido, pues ambas imágenes las cree yo en Canva.com y las dos imágenes tienen una dimensión de 600x600. Estoy usando el AndroidKoala 17. Anexaré el código de mi archivo .xml y una imagen, espero no estar cometiendo algún error muy obvio, pero es que apenas me estoy familiarizando con Android Studio. De entre las opciones que intenté salió que, mis imágenes ahora ocupan un área demasiado alta en la pantalla, aunque las imágenes estén de tamaño normal.

He probado soluciones en otros sitios y quisiera saber si existe una manera de ajustar tanto la tabla al centro de la pantalla del dispositivo, así como el contenido que hay en cada columna de la tabla al centro.
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >



        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/img1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />


        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/img2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:text="textoprueba"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
        <TextView
            android:text="text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPopup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Texto default"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgInfoPopup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/icon_whatsapp"
    android:id="@+id/wasa_icono"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />


Sería de ayuda que pusieras una foto de cómo quieres que te quede

No se NADA de android studio, pero puedo ver que las imagenes, las tienes AMBAS en el centro. No deberías tener una a la izquierda y otra a la derecha ? en los gravity.

Agrega los ImageView denro de un LinearLayout y define gravity="center", también define stretchColumns="*" , para que aplique a todas las columnas:

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

 ...
 ...
 ...

</TableRow>

